# html2canvas - render page during or after element's animation/transition

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations, html2canvas

I made button that capture the whole page using html2canvas
but my page has a loading animation from the start when the page loads.
The problem is that, when I use html2canvas, I was expecting it will render the page when the loading animation finished, but no, instead, it also renders the first frame of the animation.
is there a workaround of this?